# Python & Selenium - unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (663, 469). Other element would receive the click:

Tags: python, selenium

I have this Selenium Code that should click on a size selection button.

```
submit_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('pro_sku')

elementList = submit_button.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

elementList[3].click()
```

It works for other pages but now on one page I get this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (663, 469). Other element would receive the click:
```

I don't understand it because I can look at the browser window that Selenium opens and I normally can click on these buttons.

How can I solve this?

Someone asked for the website. Here it is: http://de.sinobiological.com/GM-CSF-CSF2-Protein-g-19491.html

Comment: Share please the website where you try to click these elements, will be much easier for us to help you. Could be that there is an overlay or popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [action_chains](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) to simulate mouse movment

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(elementList[3]).perform()
elementList[3].click()
```

> Edit

The `<a>` tags are not the actual sizes. Try

```
sizes = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('size_defaut')
sizes[3].click()
```

Comment: @Eternal_Sunshine what exactly are you trying to click?

Comment: The sizes of the product Größe:5µg 20µg 100µg 500µg 1mg

Comment: "TypeError: 'WebElement' object does not support indexing"

Comment: Ok it works. I just had to change element to elements in find_element_by_class_name THX

Comment: @Eternal_Sunshine I fixed the answer, nice catch :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Xpath for element selection and then use the following method

```
   # Click on Element 
   def element_click(self, xpath):
      xpath = re.sub('"', "'", xpath)
      browser.execute_script("""
                                 var elements = document.evaluate("%s",
                                 document,
                                 null,
                                 XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
                                 null);
                                 var im = elements.snapshotItem(0);
                                 im.click();
                                 """ %(xpath)
                                 )
```

So if your x-path is correct and item is present on DOM then definitely it will get clicked.

Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

Try below:-

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elementList[3])
```

Hope it will help you :)