# Selenium python not clickable element at point(X, Y) instead other element would receive the click(here the element neither a button nor a link)

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

[This](https://www.flipkart.com/sony-mdr-zx110-wired-headphones/p/itmehuh6zm9s7kgz?pid=ACCDZRSEYPFHAT76&srno=s_1_1&otracker=search&lid=LSTACCDZRSEYPFHAT76TANM1F&qH=a684a6245806d98f) is a link to an e-commerce website which I would like to crawl. I am searching for a way to click on Most Helpful, positive, negative, most recent and by certified buyers section and scrape the values. Heads up, it's not a button so ActionChains and Javascript code is not working on it.

I want to move from one to another either by using click or with any other methods. I tried By using javascript executor and ActionChains but I am unable to get it.

For this My Xpath is:

```
path = '//div[@class="o5jqS-"]/div[X]//div[contains(@class,"_3MuAT6")]'
```

which actually returns an element. The "X" value is replaced in a loop with 1 to 5. 1 signifying "Most helpful" and 5 signifying "By Certfied Buyers"

My code is below:

```
for j in range(0,5):

    new_xpath = xpath_hash["FirstPageReviews"]["TitleOfReviewType"].replace("[X]", "[" + str(j + 1) + "]")
    new_xpath1 = xpath_hash["FirstPageReviews"]["TitleElement"].replace("[X]", "[" + str(j + 1) + "]")
    title_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(new_xpath1)
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", title_element)
    #ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(title_element).click().perform()
```

Comment: Use actions class to move to that element first and then click it

Comment: I hope this will help for sure https://stackoverflow.com/a/45369987/6008000 Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python & Selenium - unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (663, 469). Other element would receive the click:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033859/python-selenium-unknown-error-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-663-469)

Answer (score 0):

you could use my code base on page object, i have tried this worked

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select


class SeleniumBaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver = driver
    def open(self,URL):
        self.driver.get(URL)
    def driverURLChange(self,URL):  
        print("change URL" + URL)
        self.driver.get(URL)
    def currentUrl(self):
        print("URL   " +  self.driver.current_url)
        return self.driver.current_url

    def locateElement(self, loc):
        try:
            print(loc)
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(loc))
            return element
        except:
            print ("cannot find {0} element".format(loc))
        return None

    def waitForElementInvisible(self,loc):
        #load-spinner
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver,10).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located(loc))
            return True
        except:
            print ("cannot invisibility_of_element {0} element".format(loc))
        return False            

    def send_key_with_Element(self,loc,value):
        self.locateElement(loc).clear()
        self.locateElement(loc).send_keys(value)
    def click_with_Element(self,loc):
        self.locateElement(loc).click()
    def clickElementsBySendKey(self,loc,value):
        self.locateElement(loc).send_keys(value)  




customdriver = SeleniumBaseClass(webdriver.Chrome())

customdriver.open("https://www.flipkart.com/sony-mdr-zx110-wired-headphones/p/itmehuh6zm9s7kgz?pid=ACCDZRSEYPFHAT76&srno=s_1_1&otracker=search&lid=LSTACCDZRSEYPFHAT76TANM1F&qH=a684a6245806d98f")
HelpfulTab = (By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'Most Helpful')]")
PositiveTab = (By.XPATH,"//div[contains(text(),'Positive')]")

customdriver.click_with_Element(PositiveTab)
```

Comment: i havbe change the code to use visibility_of_element_located to locate the element ,the element neeed time to display