# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 'script' must be a string while using execute_script() through Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've got an issue with browser.execute_script while using selenium with python. There is an element that i'd like to click (it's xpath below)

```
"//*[@id='listFav_FI410_23244709400000_FAGNNURROR_IPOF_APP_P43070_W43070A_CP000A001_40']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"
```

I try to do it with:

```
navMenu = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='listFav_FI410_23244709400000_FAGNNURROR_IPOF_APP_P43070_W43070A_CP000A001_40']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")
time.sleep(3)
browser.execute_script(navMenu.click())
```

And it works (So it clicks desired element) but right after doing it it throws an error that terminates the script:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 'script' must be a string
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to skip this error? Thx for wasting your time on helping me :)

Comment: You are passing a function call to `.execute_script`, you need to pass it a string, or just call `navMenu.click()`

Comment: just use `navMenu.click()`

Comment: @RyanWilson ok, so what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: replace `browser.execute_script(navMenu.click())` with `navMenu.click()`

Comment: @Nihal - it doesn't work- it throws error "element is not visible"

Comment: `navMenu.click()` is the correct way to do it. in which line are you getting error?

Comment: @Nihal in the line in which navMenu.click() is, so I know for a fact that this is not correct way of doing it. This element is generated by JS. That is why I have to use .execute_script. As I said- it works because i can see that it clicks defined element. .click() doesn't work at all- script crashes when it tries to execute .click()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32066753/7053679

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: 'script' must be a string
```

...implies that the method **`execute_script()`** was invoked with *wrong type* of parameters.

The [**`execute_script()`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) method is defined as:

```
execute_script(script, *args)
    Synchronously Executes JavaScript in the current window/frame.

Where:
    script: The JavaScript to execute
    *args: Any applicable arguments for your JavaScript.
```

In your code trial `executeScript()` method will take the reference of the element as **arguments[0]** along with the method to be performed (in this case `click()`) and the reference should be provided thereafter. So @Andersson's solution should have worked.

```
navMenu = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='listFav_FI410_23244709400000_FAGNNURROR_IPOF_APP_P43070_W43070A_CP000A001_40']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", navMenu)
```

You can find a detailed discussion in [What does argument [0] and argument [1] mean in javascriptexecutor in Selenium WebDriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49871432/what-does-argument-0-and-argument-1-mean-in-javascriptexecutor-in-selenium-w)

---

The hint to your main issue is the error `element not visible` which implies either of the following cases:

- You are trying to invoke `click()` even before *the element is visible/clickable*
- Element is not within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) when `click()` was invoked.

### Solution

Two pottential solutions will be as follows:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* as follows:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  # other lines of code
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='listFav_FI410_23244709400000_FAGNNURROR_IPOF_APP_P43070_W43070A_CP000A001_40']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"))).click()
  ```
- Use `executeScript()` method to bring the element within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) and then invoke `click()` as follows:

  ```
  navMenu = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='listFav_FI410_23244709400000_FAGNNURROR_IPOF_APP_P43070_W43070A_CP000A001_40']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]")
  browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",navMenu);
  navMenu.click()
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much! WebDriverWait for the element to be clickable works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
browser.execute_script(navMenu.click())
```

try

```
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', navMenu)
```

or

```
navMenu.click()
```

Comment: It doesn't cause any errors now, but it doesn't actually click anything. I added simple `print('ooo')` right after `browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', navMenu)` and I get ooo in the Shell, but nothing happens on the website. I can't use `navMenu.click()` as webdriver doesn't see the element

Comment: Share HTML or/and page URL

Comment: sorry but I can't share the link as this website contains condfidential information (you would have to log in and obviously I cannot give you credentials). I think that the root of this problem is that the entire website is generated by couple Java Script scripts. I've noticed that when I use `navMenu.click()` in shell (while script is running) it works, but first I have to actually click somewhere Is there a way to activate Java Script?

Comment: Or maybe there is a way to tell script not to terminate process after receiving error mentioned in my question? Simpy ignore it and go with another task because as I said- it works, script actually clicks desired element- the problem is that it crashes right after it (but the element that I wanted to be loaded is loaded)

Comment: `browser.execute_script(navMenu.click())` just executes `navMenu.click()`. It doesn't matter how you call the method. Using as `browser.execute_script(navMenu.click())` make no sense. Try to implement proper ExplicitWait

Comment: I know that it is weir but if I use `navMenu.click()` i get error" element not visible" and the script doesn't even click anything. In case of  `browser.execute_script(navMenu.click())` script clicks the element and crashes afterwards because of the error from first post.

Comment: Try to wait until element is visble

Comment: Thx for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to execute a script is to **actually write a JavaScript script!**.

The `click()` function of selenium is on the element of the DOM you have located not a script.

As @Andersson suggested try `browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', navMenu)`

I can see you added a sleep for 3 seconds... Using Selenium we generally use `WebDriverWait` you can learn more about wait's [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html).

If it's too complicated you can just start with `driver.implicitly_wait(3)` instead of sleep.

**Edit:**

If the Element is not displayed yet you can just use `navMenu.is_displayed()`

Hope this helps you.

Comment: It doesn't cause any errors now, but it doesn't actually click anything. I added simple `print('ooo')` right after `browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', navMenu)` and I get ooo in the Shell, but nothing happens on the website. Thanks for advice (about using WebDriverWait).

Comment: my recommendation is to use wait for element!

Comment: I did, and somehow it sees it but then cannot click on it as it is not visible: `try:#waits until element is prestent
    element7_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='listFav_FI410_23244709400000_FAGNNURROR_IPOF_APP_P43070_W43070A_CP000A001_40']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]"))#web element identification
    WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(element7_present)#max sleep time defined
except TimeoutException:#error message definition
    print('Timed out waiting for page to load')`

Comment: I know that it sounds stupid- there is wait and script sees it as it goes to another action but then cannot perform the click as "element is not visible"

Comment: see edit... if it does not help it may be because the site is built in Angular

Comment: Thx for trying to help me :)