# Selenium Python "script must be a string"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to make Driver.get() work for multiple different URL's but that seems to be impossible as .get has to contain a string , it can not contain a variable that is a string and neither can you convert it to a string in the process.

```
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
TradeURL1 = "https://app.libertex.com/products/crypto/Bitcoin/" #User stated
#driver1.execute_script(driver1.get(str(TradeURL1)))
driver1.get(TradeURL1)#https://app.libertex.com/products/metal/XAUUSD
```

declaring the URL as a variable and placing the variable name in the .get throws the script must be a string error .

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: 'script' must be a string
```

but placing the URL in like this

```
driver1.get("https://app.libertex.com/products/metal/XAUUSD")
```

works perfectly fine . how are you supposed to make your code versatile and adapt it if you cant place a variable name there(the URL is changing  throughout the code)
Is there a way around this other than using multiple drivers (because i will not even know how many drivers i will be using + using multiple drivers takes more processing power and is inefficient)

similar question
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187248/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-unknown-error-script)

edit after @DeepSpace

```
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome()
TradeURL1 = "https://app.libertex.com/products/crypto/Bitcoin/" #User stated
#driver1.execute_script(driver1.get(str(TradeURL1)))
driver1.get(TradeURL1)#https://app.libertex.com/products/metal/XAUUSD
time.sleep(5)
driver1 = login()
```

the driver1 = login()
login() is a subroutine i have built, when i run the code(works for when you actually put a string in get) it works fine.
But when running with driver1.get(TradeURL1)
shows this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#login-field"}
```

backtracking what i had done up to that point ..changing driver1.get("Actual string") to driver1.get(TradeURL1) and sure enough the issue was the script must be a string  error ... im confusedas you are @DeepSpace

Comment: I doubt this is actually what's going on. Provide full [mcve] + stacktrace

Comment: yes i was amazed and confused aswell

Comment: `.get` has virtually no way to detect if it was given a variable or a string literal, hence I asked for a **reproducible** example including the full stacktrace. As of now, this is not reproducible

Comment: After your edit: please take a step back. The error you now show us is completely different than the original error. Take the time to understand exactly what causes which error.

Comment: No im saying that the second error i showed only exists because of the first one.My code worked fine until i placed TradeURL in the get()

Comment: You were saying that get() has no way of knowing if it has a litereal  or a variable. Could you explain this?